# How can I import a single photo from Mac to iPhone library?

Tags: iphone, import, apps

I want to import a single image file from my computer into my iPhone library so that I can, from there, import it into the LINE app. I do not want to sync my iPhone with my computer, because I only want to import the one photo, not all of my photos.

I tried Googling for this information but the only instructions I found were about syncing. I also tried Googling about importing photos into LINE but I did not find any information other than that the app draws its photos from the iPhone library.

Comment: How about emailing it to yourself?

Comment: @laurencemadill, if I email it to myself, how do I get it from my Gmail app into the iPhone library?

Comment: I think if you open the message you should see an attachment at the bottom, click the attachment (but not on the googledrive triangle icon), and it will open the image for viewing. If you tap again, it will show the 'done' button etc, and you have the Share button at the bottom left, tap this and tap 'Save Image'. It may prompt that Gmail wants access to Photos, you need to OK this otherwise it won't have permissions to save

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. I had previously dragged a photo into a Gmail body, but apparently doing that does not show the photo as an attachment (with the GoogleDrive triangle icon) when the email is opened in the Gmail app on the iPhone, whereas by attaching the photo using the paperclip button allows it to then show up as an open-able attachment in the Gmail app that can be shared to the Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Email the image as an attachment to yourself. Then open attachment in your email app on your iPhone to view the image. Tap the image to see additional buttons, one of which will be to save the image to your iPhone.

Option 2: Use messages app to send yourself the photo as message. Then save it as above.

Option 3: Use DropBox, iCloud, or any third party file sharing service. You just copy the file to a folder on your computer and the photo magically appears on your iPhone device.

Option 4: You can select single photos when tethered with USB cable manually to sync an iPhone with a Mac using iTunes app. This is the method to sync other things such as pdf files, music files, etc.

Option 5: If you have airplay enabled on your Mac (recent macs only), you can drag and drop the photo file on the iPhone icon. Airplay works if enabled on both devices.

Each method has its usefulness and applicability. But if none of these work for you, then don't overlook the obvious: Open the photo on your computer screen and then take a photo of it with your iPhone. Nothing beats a quick shot.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to do this I use the Messages app on the Mac to send it to myself using my phone number. The photo then appears on my phone in an iMessage, which I can then save straight to the camera roll. This works both ways too, so you can send photos from your iPhone back to your Mac.